# Show Skip, Take, OrderBy in ServiceStack metadata page

Tags: properties, servicestack, metadata

In some of my services I am using ServiceStack AutoQuery to greater simplify data access. It is very helpful.

When looking at the metadata page it correctly shows all data operations available however it does not show the default IQuery ones which are Skip, Take, OrderBy, and OrderByDesc. I would like these to show since they are query operations. I tried several things but could not figure it out.

I thought the AutoQuery ignore properties would be the solution, but I am not sure what that does as they still don't show.

```
    var autoQuery = new AutoQueryFeature() { OrderByPrimaryKeyOnPagedQuery = true };
    autoQuery.IgnoreProperties.Remove("Skip");
    autoQuery.IgnoreProperties.Remove("Take");
    autoQuery.IgnoreProperties.Remove("OrderBy");
    autoQuery.IgnoreProperties.Remove("OrderByDesc");

    Plugins.Add(autoQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

The metadata pages have now been modified to also show definitions of built-in ServiceStack types like `QueryBase` in metadata pages [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/4dc1693681dbb6a0247f14ae5d6f1846ec2ce309).

This change is available from v4.0.41+ of ServiceStack that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: Commit reference link fail :)